# If $x= m-m^2-2$ then find $x^4+3x^3+2x^2-11x+6$ where m is a cube root of unity

Tags: complex-analysis

If $$x= m-m^2-2$$ then find $$x^4+3x^3+2x^2-11x+6$$ where $m$ is a cube root of unity.

**My try:**
Since $ m+ m^2+1=0$ the value of $x$ is $-1$.

Let $f(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x^2-11x+6$
then $ f(-1)=5$ So the answer is $5$.

Am I correct? In my book it says that answer is $1$. Please help me to identify my mistake.

Comment: If $x=-1$ then $m^2-m+1=0$ so $m$ is not a cube root of unity.

Comment: If $x=-1$, then $m$ is a cube root of -1, not 1.

Answer (score 4):

$$x=m-m^2-2=-(m+m^2+1)+2m-1=2m-1$$
And $2m-1 \neq1$, here is your mistake. Then we can continue our calculations :

$$f(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x^2-11x+6\\=16m^4-32m^3+24m^2-8m+1+24 m^3-36 m^2+18 m-3+8 m^2-8 m+2-22m+11+6\\=16 m^4-8 m^3-4 m^2-20 m+17\\=16m^2(m^2+m+1)-24m^3-20m^2-20m+17\\=-24m^3-20m^2-20m+17=-24m(m^2+m+1)+4m^2+4m+17\\=4m^2+4m+17\\=4(m^2+m+1)+13\\=13$$

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is a **primitive** cube root of unity, $m^2+m+1=0$ is correct, but that just gives
$$ x = m-m^2-2 = -2\pm i\sqrt{3}. $$
Given $p(z)=z^4+3z^3+2z^2-11z+6$, we have:
$$ q(z) = p(z-2) = z^4-5z^3+8z^2-15z+28 $$
and
$$ p(x) = q(\pm i\sqrt{3}) =\color{red}{13}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Replacing $x=m-m^2-2$ in your given polynomial function, we have

$$f(x)=m^8-4 m^7+11 m^6-19 m^5+24 m^4-21 m^3+23 m^2-15 m+28$$ as a result. Now, noticing that $m$ is a cube root of $-1$, this is equal to

$$f(x)=m^2-4 m^1+11 m^0-19 m^2+24 m^1-21 m^0+23 m^2-15 m+28=$$

$$5m^2+5m+18=5(m^2+m+1)+13=\color{blue}{13}.$$